# JQuery Do something when data returned from .post

Tags: php, jquery, return, .post

I have a site that is sending off using the .post function in JQuery to run a php script. This script adds some data to a database but if the data already exists in the database it doesn't add the data. Depending on whether the data is added or not I want the javascript to do different things. I don't know how to get the php to return a value that says "data entered" or "data not entered" so the javascript can use that value to decided upon it next action.

Here is the javascript, I only want the append to happen if the php returns that the data was entered into the database.

```
$('#addpios').click(function() {
  var scopesheetidvalue = $("#scopesheetid").val();
  var piovalue = $("#pioselected").val();
$.post("addpio.php", { scopesheetid: scopesheetidvalue, pionumber: piovalue },function(data){
$('#pioslist').append("<li><input class='removepio' type='submit' value='"+piovalue+"' /><span class='listitem'>PIO "+piovalue+"</span></li>");} 
    );   
});
```

Here is the PHP

```
$scopesheetid = $_POST['scopesheetid'];
$pionumber = $_POST['pionumber'];
$alreadyexisitssql = "SELECT * FROM [ScopesheetPIO] WHERE [ScopesheetID]='$scopesheetid' AND [PIONumber]='$pionumber'";
$alreadyexisits=odbc_exec($connection,$alreadyexisitssql);

if(odbc_fetch_row($alreadyexisits)){
//retrun a value that says the data already exists
}
else{
    $addpiosql = "INSERT INTO [ScopesheetPIO] ([ScopesheetID], [PIONumber]) VALUES ('$scopesheetid', '$pionumber')";
    $addpioresult=odbc_exec($connection,$addpiosql);
//retrun a vlaue that the data was added
}
```

What I really want is a way to pass a value from the PHP script back into the Jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would modify your jQuery to the following:

```
$.post('addpio.php', { ... }, function(data) {
    if (data.result) {
        $('#pioslist').append(...);
    }
}, 'json');
```

In your PHP file, use this when the data is inserted:

```
echo json_encode(array(
    'result' => TRUE
));
```

Use this when the data already exists:

```
echo json_encode(array(
    'result' => FALSE
));
```

Comment: Thanks that makes sense but I am getting stuck. When I run the PHP on its own it makes the JSON bit but when I run the JQuery it doesn't seem to be able to detect the JSON.

Comment: Have you included `, 'json'` after `function(data) { ... }`? Also, what is `#addpios`? Is it a button or a link?

Comment: Can you `alert(data);` or `console.log(data);` and paste the JSON here?

Comment: Sorry here it is
`$('#addpios').click(function() {
  var scopesheetidvalue = $("#scopesheetid").val();
  var piovalue = $("#pioselected").val();
$.post('addpio.php', { scopesheetid: scopesheetidvalue, pionumber: piovalue }, function(data) {
    alert(data);
}, 'json');
     
});`
and the PHP
    `if(odbc_fetch_row($alreadyexisits)){
    // Return a value that says the data already exists
    echo json_encode(array(
    'result' => FALSE
));
    }
    else{
    // Return a value that the data was added
    echo json_encode(array(
    'result' => TRUE
));
    }`

Comment: I worked out what it was, I was also echoing out a whole table of results on the page which was confusing it. Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1):

Build an array in PHP and output it as JSON. Then inspect the returned JSON in your script.

```
if(odbc_fetch_row($alreadyexists)){
    // Return a value that says the data already exists
    $result = array(
        "error" => "Data already exists"
    );
} else {
    // Database stuff goes here...
    // Return a value that the data was added
    $result = array(
        "success" => 1
    );
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

JavaScript `$.post` callback:

```
function(data) {
    if(data.success) {
        // Append element to HTML
    } else {
        // An error occurred, inform the user
        // Don't actually use alert(), this is just for demonstrating purposes
        alert(data.error);
    }
}
```

Later on, you can then create more complex responses with extra data by simply adding them to the `$result` array and reading them from `data` in your JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Write anything in your PHP that you'll test in your callback function :

PHP

```
if(odbc_fetch_row($alreadyexisits)){
 echo "ko";
}
else{
    $addpiosql = "INSERT INTO [ScopesheetPIO] ([ScopesheetID], [PIONumber]) VALUES ('$scopesheetid', '$pionumber')";
    $addpioresult=odbc_exec($connection,$addpiosql);
    echo "ok";
}
```

JS

```
$.post("addpio.php", { scopesheetid: scopesheetidvalue, pionumber: piovalue },function(data){
    if( data == 'ok' ) {
        $('#pioslist').append("<li><input class='removepio' type='submit' value='"+piovalue+"' /><span class='listitem'>PIO "+piovalue+"</span></li>");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily pass data from a script to jQuery. IMO I think its best to use JSON as its much more neater.

```
PHP (for example):
$arrayOfData=array("val1"=>"value","val2"=>"value");

//encode it
$arrayOfData=json_encode($arrayOfData);

//print it on screen
echo $arrayOfData;
```

And then get it in jQuery using the .`getJSON`.

```
$.getJSON("url_of_php_fle",function(myData){

//now use myData as the array:
alert(myData.val1);//which will give you "value" as what you set in PHP

}):
```

It really is that easy.